# Display a defined part of a chart chart

Tags: charts

I'm using a chart control in one of my projects and I want to make sure that only a part of it is displayed.
I spigo, let's say that there are 100 columns, I would like you to see only the first 10, then with the bar below you can move along it always with the same level of zoom.
Thank you all.

Comment: It might help if you hinted at the framework, system or language you are using to program this, don't you think?

Comment: Yes sure.
Visual study written in C #.
.NETFramework, Version = v4.5.2

Comment: No good soul ??

Comment: you may want to learn [ask], then edit your question to provide more details.